# Computation of the Fredhom index in Floer theory

Tags: differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

I have been reading [Salamon's lecture notes on Floer homology](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/floer.pdf), and to compute the Fredholm index of operators they use the fact that the spectral flow of $A(s)$ is the Fredholm index. Now in the proof of theorem 2.2, that is the index formula, the author claims that we can assume that $\Psi(s,t)$ is such that
$$
\Psi(s,t)=
\begin{cases}
\Psi^{+}(t) &\text{for }t\geq  T\\
\Psi^{-}(t) &\text{for }t\leq -T
\end{cases}  
$$
and such that $\Psi(s,1)$ has only regular crossings.

However I am not quite sure why this is true. I thought about using a transversality argument to obtain that $\Psi(s,1)$ only has regular crossings but I am not sure how to obtain the other conditions .

It's easy to see that we can find $\Psi''(s)$ such that it only has simple crossings and such that $\Psi''(s)=\Psi(1)^+$ for $s\geq t$ and analogous for $\Psi^-(1)$. This essentialy follows from transversality.

The main problem I am having is that the transversality arguments here work well for curves since these are $1$ dimensional but if we try to consider something of the form $\Psi(s,t)$ we will run into trouble.

So I am trying to use the $\Psi''(s)$ to modify the original $\Psi(s,t)$ assoaciated witht the symplectic matrix but I am not getting anywhere.

Does anyone have any insight on this ? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.